# What's the meaning of this "updog" joke?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

From "The Office" S2E13

> **Jim:** Is it me or does it smell like updog in here?
> **Michael:** What's updog?
> **Jim:** Nothing much. What's up with you?

Where is the funny point?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146481/meaning-of-dog-in-the-updog-joke

Answer (score 27):

"Dog" or "dawg" is a slang way to talk to a close friend (especially in some American cultural dialects)

So "What's up dawg?" means "How are you, mate?"

The joke is, Person A says "It smells like updog." (updog is a made up word).  Person B doesn't know the meaning of "updog", so he asks "What's updog?" Person A has tricked person B into saying "What's up dawg?" in a casual slangy way. It is the trick that is the joke.

Don't try to emulate, and start calling your friends "dawg" it won't come across as natural.

Comment: A guy at work submitted a pull request (PR) to the code repository with the comment "fixes the updog algorithm".  So being unfamiliar with this joke l bit and asked "whats updog?" and got the response featured in this question.  Nasty trick to play on a coworker, I must say.